# SQL Join queries on related data

Tags: join

I have data table in SQL Server that looks like the following [Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZMfg.jpg)

The data table has Columns TranID nvarchar(50), Amt decimal(38,2), IsCancelled bit.
If a transaction is called, the column named IsCancelled has boolean value 0, but when the transaction is called, a duplicate record is inserted with the column IsCancelled set to 1. I need to write a query that will return records only when a row does not have a corresponding cancelled transaction. In my case, only the record with TranID XYZ should appear be returned from the query. The record with TranID ABC should not be returned since it has a corresponding IsCancelled with bollean value 1. I could run a cursor query for records with IsCancelled set to 0 and use it to determine if there is any corrosponding IsCancelled  = 1 and then discard the record, but this looping multiple records causes delay. Is there a way I can write a single query to handle this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table to itself like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE transaction
LEFT JOIN MYTABLE cancelled ON (transaction.TranID = cancelled.TranID AND transaction.Amt = cancelled.Amt AND cancelled.isCancelled = 1)
WHERE transaction.isCancelled = 0
AND cancelled.TranID IS NULL
```

If your it is guaranteed that if your table contains two rows with same `TranId` it means that it was cancelled, the query can be simplified to

```sql
SELECT TranId, Amt, 0 AS isCancelled FROM MYTABLE transaction
GROUP BY TranId
HAVING COUNT(isCancelled) = 1
```

Creating index on `TranID` is advised for both scenarios

Comment: Thanks, in my scenario, the same TranId will appear twice if the transaction is called. The first query you suggested yields duplicate results in my scenario, but the second one works, except I have to include all the columns in the group by clause. This serves as the answer in my scenario.

Comment: I've slightly updated my answer to fix first query

Comment: Indeed the first answer is now the perfect choice. Thanks for your effort. I was going to loop the cursor variable, but you simplified it.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question.